# Discriminatory sum - Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have 2 tables:

1. contains the bank with the limit that i can use and the priority to use(which limits i should use first)
2. contains my movimentations and the value of the documents

I need to issue invoices and for that i need to pass the bank that will be used for the bank slip. I can only send 20 invoices per batch. My problem is that my client want to maximize the limit in each bank so the documents should receive the right bank according to the past documents and the limit. Ex:

I have 5 docs

```
111 - value: 5
222 - value: 4
333 - value: 7
444 - value: 1
555 - value: 2
```

with 3 banks

```
a - limit:15 order:1
b - limit:10 order:2
c - limit:20 order:3
```

the procedure should set to the moviments the following:

```
111 - Bank A
222 - Bank A
333 - Bank B
444 - Bank A
555 - Bank A
```

where the 3 was B because he would break the limit of A considering the sum of the past documents that used the bank A(9) and is less than the sum of the documents that used B(0)

how can i do this in a single select? i cant use loops since it is really slow and the volume of the processed documents make i get a lot of time-outs

```
declare @table_bank table(
                                        pk int,
                                        bank_name varchar(50),
                                        total_limit money,
                                        priority_use int
)

declare @table_doc table(
                    pk int,
                    valor money
)
insert into @table_doc(pk, valor) values(1, 5)
insert into @table_doc(pk, valor) values(2, 4)
insert into @table_doc(pk, valor) values(3, 7)
insert into @table_doc(pk, valor) values(4, 1)
insert into @table_doc(pk, valor) values(5, 2)

insert into @table_bank(pk, bank_name, total_limit, priority_use) values(1, 'aaa', 15, 1)
insert into @table_bank(pk, bank_name, total_limit, priority_use) values(1, 'bbb', 10, 2)
insert into @table_bank(pk, bank_name, total_limit, priority_use) values(1, 'ccc', 20, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation round-robin is a very reasonable approach

```
select t.*,
       ceiling(row_number() over (order by value desc) * 1.0 / <n>) as bank_number
from t;
```

This is not best under all circumstances, but it is fast and does a reasonably good job.

Comment: And what i put in <n>?

Comment: @BrendonFernandes . . . That would be the number of banks.